# How to install python-opencv in amazon-sagemaker?

Tags: python, opencv, amazon-sagemaker

I installed the OpenCV package by `pip install opencv-python`.

When I import cv2 in my code.

```py
import cv2
```

I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_324/571303353.py in <module>
----> 1 import cv2

~/.conda/envs/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py in <module>
      6 import sys
      7 
----> 8 from .cv2 import *
      9 from .cv2 import _registerMatType
     10 from . import mat_wrapper

ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1072878) are some solutions for this error but seemly need root permission.

```
apt-get update -y
apt-get install libglib2.0-0
```

When I run these commands in the terminal I got the following errors.

```
(studiolab) studio-lab-user@default:~/sagemaker-studiolab-notebooks/vit/ViT-pytorch$ apt-get update -y
Reading package lists... Done
E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 4):

This problem has been solved.

```sh
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip install opencv-python-headless
```

More details can be found in [here](https://github.com/aws/studio-lab-examples/issues/10#issuecomment-985614988).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. With this line, you can install the glib dependency for **Amazon Sagemaker Studio Lab**. Just run it on your notebook cell.

```
! conda install glib=2.51.0 -y
```

You also can create another virtual environment for your session that contains glib:

```
! conda create -n glib-test -c defaults -c conda-forge python=3 glib=2.51.0` -y
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this ImportError too and Thanks to @AmirMasoud's suggested solution. After running `! conda install glib=2.51.0 -y` in my virtual environment, now cv2 is imported successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this order:

```
!pip uninstall -y opencv-python
!conda install glib=2.51.0 -y
!pip install opencv-python
!pip install opencv-python-headless
```